When copyright expire, all EULA conditions also expire?
When software copyright expire, or court/government revoke copyright, or software creator put software in public domain, all EULA contract conditions also expire?

No. A EULA is a contract, and it ends when the contract says it ends.

True, but maybe irrelevant? If the software is no longer copyrighted, you can get a new copy without having to agree to the EULA.

@Barmar It may be more complicated than that: new copies may not be physically available, so the only version you may have access to is the version you hold under the EULA.  What happens if the EULA you originally agreed to said you promise never to take a copy of that version even after the copyright expires?

Of course, that takes precedence.

@Barmar EULAs often include warranties, support and IP rights indemnification. Prime example: Red Hat Linux. You can get the software legally through other means (CentOS et. al.) but companies pay thousands for these benefits.

@user71659 Indeed, but I interpreted the OP as being more concerned about the licensee's obligations/restrictions.
